# How to get the total number of objects created in javascript for a class?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Lets say I have the following code snippet:

```
function Airplane(id) { 
  this.id = id;  
}

var air1 = new Airplane(234);
var air2 = new Airplane(235);
var air3 = new Airplane(236);
```

Is there any way to get the total number of Airplane objects created something like `Airplane.getCreatedLength()`?

Comment: What's "distinct"? `var air1 = new Airplane(234); var air2 = new Airplane(234);` are air1 and air2 distinct or identical? What's the practical use of this?

Answer (score 4):

You could keep track of those in a property attached to the constructor:

```
function Airplane(id) {
  this.id = id;
  Airplane.instances += 1;
}

Airplane.instances = 0;

var air1 = new Airplane(234);
var air2 = new Airplane(235);
var air3 = new Airplane(236);

console.log(Airplane.instances) // 3
```

Comment: While this answers the question, it seems purely statistical. It only says how many instances were ever created, not how many are used, exist in a certain context etc. I mean, it's neat, but I see little practical use for it. That's more about how the question is formulated than any critique of the answer though.

Comment: Each instance could have a `destroy` method that decrements this number. But I agree in general, I'm not sure what the use of this is, perhaps an XY problem?